# Client Side validations not working in jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I searched and found lot of answers, still i am not able to validate fields in my jQuery UI Dialog. Please suggest appropriate ways for the same.

**Parent View:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Add New">
    <p>Div content</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
        $('#btnAddNew').click(function () {
            $('#dialog').dialog
            ({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load("@Url.Action("AddNewFormPart1")"); //Rendering Partial View
                }
            });
        });
    });
<script/>
```

**Partial View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitFormPart1", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formPart1" }))
 {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div>......
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnSubmitFormPart1"/>
    </div>
 }
```

Comment: is jquery-unobtrusive is included?

Comment: Yes, jquery-unobtrusive.js is included.

Comment: Open developer tools in browser - > Console tab and check if any JS error there

Comment: No JS errors are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validator should parse partial page after loading partial page. if you are using Unobtrusive Validation:

```
$(this).load('@Url.Action("AddNewFormPart1")', function(response, status, xhr){
    var form = $("#AddNewFormPart1");
    form.removeData('validator');
    form.removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
})
```

Comment: Could you please tell which version of jQuery supports .done(). I am getting JS error. I was using jquery-1.7.1.js.

Comment: Answer have been updated. for more information see [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because your content are loaded after the plugin call!
You need to call the validation plugin after loading the partial view as follows(Notice the `.done(function*({})` helper).

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
    $('#btnAddNew').click(function () {
        alert('Add New clicked!');
        $('#dialog').dialog
        ({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("AddNewFormPart1")").done(function(){

                    //CALL YOUR VALIDATION PLUGIN HERE
                    //$('#formPart1').validate({...});
                }); //Rendering Partial View
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'done'. "

Comment: Are you using an old version of jQuery? I suggest you use jQuery 1.9

Comment: I was using jquery-1.7.1.js. When i changed it to jquery-1.9.1.js, it gives js error in jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js.